# iOS app store app name reservation through testflight beta application

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I've had an iOS Swift app in iTunes Connect TestFlight beta for almost 9 months and I am pushing regular build updates to it. Will this app name be reserved automatically or do I have to take another route to reserve the same app name?

Currently, when I am trying to create a new app with the same name using ItunesConnect, an error occurs, saying "The app name you entered is already being used..." Should I believe confidently that this app name will not be allocated to another developer account and I can publish the app under this same name using the same build configuration and bundle identifier in the future, say in around 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the app name you have chosen on iTunes account will not be allocated to another developer account until you or Apple removes or disables your app from your iTunes account. And you can publish app with the same name in future.

> **[Apple Guideline For iOS App Name Selection](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) (Revised)**
>
> **2.3.7** Choose a unique app name, assign keywords that accurately describe your app, and don’t try to pack any of your metadata with trademarked terms, popular app names, or other irrelevant phrases just to game the system. App names must be limited to 30 characters and should not include prices, terms, or descriptions that are not the name of the app. App subtitles are a great way to provide additional context for your app; they must follow our standard metadata rules and should not include inappropriate content, reference other apps, or make unverifiable product claims. Apple may modify inappropriate keywords at any time.

Comment: Once the app is published then How will the team able to test the Testflight Beta builds ? Is it possible say, v 1.x  to publish on the app store while the team can still use testflight with same bundle name for internal testing the versions higher than v 1.x.y?

Comment: Published build cannot be used for TestFlight beta testing as both are uploaded using different provisioning profile, Distributed app need Production provisioning profile and TestFlight need AdHod provisioning profile. You need to upload another build for testFlight

Comment: It means we should use Ad Hoc build in the option from Xcode while making an Archive Or while creating a distribution provisonal profile, 2 profiles must be generated one with Ad Hoc and One with App Store options. The first one would be used for Tesflight beta distribution while second one will be used for App Store upload.. right ?